# Named Range "name" vs name

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2003, vba

I have a ridiculous problem in Excel 2003 where I want to reference a Range I have defined myself, with names such as *Div1, Div2, Div3* etc.

I have a macro that determines whether I need to use *Div1, Div2, Div3* etc. and I then need to use *VLOOKUP* and *MATCH* with these different ranges.

**However:**

`MATCH("ValueSearched", Div1, 0)` works fine, but

`MATCH("ValueSearched", "Div1", 0)` fails

Since *Div1* is determined programmatically, it is only stored as a string and I cannot use it.

I understand that in normal programming, you never really reference values like this and would use a hash table or similar, but I thought Excel would have a better work around as everything is done runtime.

Any suggestions on how I can dynamically reference these ranges?

Comment: INDIRECT works, thank you. I will consider new names!

Comment: What is the error you're receiving? And are you doing this from a worksheet function, or from VBA?  The first method should work on a worksheet, but **can't** work in VBA without additional assignment. The second method *ought* to work in VBA but won't work from a worksheet function.

Answer (score 0):

pnuts solved it.

Have you tried =MATCH("ValueSearched",INDIRECT(Div1),0)